# Entity Framework : Filter query by property of a child type

Tags: c#, entity-framework, children

I have model as below

```
class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

class Employee : Person
{
    public string Dep { get; set; }
}

class Client : Person
{
    public string Type { get; set; }
}
```

Now I would like to query `Person` by a property of `Employee` as follows

```
context.Set<Person>().Where(x => ((Employee)x).Dep == "dep").ToList();
```

But I get the following error

> Unable to cast the type 'DomainModel.Person' to type
>   'DomainModel.Employee'. LINQ to Entities only supports casting EDM
>   primitive or enumeration types.

I know that I could simply use

```
context.Set<Employee>().Where(x => x.Dep == "dep").ToList();
```

But the problem is that I use a generic search control, that control can deal only with one type to search into, the search criteria are passed to this control as lambda expressions of that determined type and search statements are also returned by the search control as lambda expressions that then are passed as predicate to the `Where` method, now I would like to use this search control to search `Employee` and `Person` at the same time, and since the search control can deal with only one type I passed the parent type to it which is `Person` so that I can access all its children types properties in the search, but I faced the problem mentioned above. Any idea?

Comment: Can you post some code for your search control?

Comment: It is a very big chunk of code, but conceptually it is almost same as search control in this link http://www.palmmedia.de/blog/2012/2/18/aspnet-mvc-generic-filtering-based-on-expressions

Comment: Is the `Person` class part of EF inheritance (TPH, TPT or TPC)? Or is just a base class? In other words, does `context.Set<Person>().ToList()` work?

Comment: The inheritance type is TPH. Yes, it does work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When it comes to EF inheritance, the `cast` operator is not supported in LINQ to Entities query. However, the `is` and `as` operator are perfectly supported, so the correct way of writing such filters is like this:

```
context.Set<Person>()
    .Where(x => x is Employee && (x as Employee).Dep == "dep")
    .ToList();
```

Comment: What about expressions of type Func<Employee,object> ? when I try ((x as Employee).MyRefType) in an Include for example, it throws and exception saying "Specified include path is not valid Employee doesn't declare a navigation property with the name MyRefType" , how do I solve this?

Comment: Unfortunately neither EF6 nor latest EF Core has a solution for including derived entity navigation properties. See for instance https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45787939/materializing-an-icollection-structure-containing-subclasses/45795052#45795052 for one workaround, but it's not generally applicable and requires query materialization and post processing.